# SevenZipSharp in C# Compress files with all path folders

Tags: c#, 7zip

I have some code

```
SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll");//x64    
var cmpr = new SevenZipCompressor();
cmpr.CompressionFinished += (s, e) => { dof.DoFinishEvent(); cmpr = null; };
cmpr.BeginCompressDirectory("C:\\58", "C:\\Table\files\today\58.7z");
```

This code is work, but when I open 58.7z I Must to open all folders(table/files/today and then I see what inside). Maybe isset some possible to save without absolute path?
Thanks!

Comment: have you consulted the documentation for `SevenZipSharp` most of these 3rd party library's have documentation with working examples

Answer (score 1):

According to [the source code](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SevenZip/SevenZipCompressor.cs), there is a boolean flag for exactly this purpose:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the value indicating whether to preserve the directory structure.
/// </summary>
public bool DirectoryStructure { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution

```
cmpr.DirectoryStructure = false;
```